# I can not able to edit cell second time after promising in 'afterCellEdit' event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

See my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fkJqM8at8odqXOTYZ8wV?p=preview):

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridOptionsApi = gridApi;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $scope.gridOptionsApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.gridOptionsApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, deferred.promise);
            //Making my operations here
            setTimeout(function () {
            if(true)
            {
              console.log('sdg');
              deferred.resolve();
            }
            else{
              deferred.reject();
            }
            }, 3000, 1);
        });
     }
```

I am making some operation after cell edit in `$scope.gridOptionsApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit()` event
I set `setSavePromise` here but after that row is not editable more...

I want to edit row second time...

See my plunkr for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You need to return deffered promise from the function $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi

Code:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridOptionsApi = gridApi;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $scope.gridOptionsApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
            $scope.gridOptionsApi.rowEdit.setSavePromise(rowEntity, deferred.promise);
            //Making my operations here
            setTimeout(function () {
            if(true)
            {
              console.log('sdg');
              deferred.resolve();
            }
            else{
              deferred.reject();
            }
            }, 3000, 1);
        });
        return deffered.promise;
     }
```

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdjHoGgTyMxcfP5oLsxN?p=preview)

Comment: @Kandarp: I am double clicking on the Name column on any name, editing it and then again double clicking it to edit, it is allowing me to do that.

Comment: there is spelling mistake in ur plunkr ....use deferred instead deffered...now check ..it will not work @V31

Comment: any help? ...please.. @V31